Can code using GOTO be converted GOTO-less algorithmically?
My impression is yes, and probably it is achievable even in polynomial time, but I am not sure.
The important thing I can see is that the "structured" control structures can be embedded into each other like a stack, making the execution similar to a tree walking. Goto violates it.
However, I think, somehow "cutting the tree" on the GOTO statements and their target labels, maybe a similar block structure could be achieved as in the structured programming, only the branching conditions should be constructed well.

You might also look into two equivalent notions in formal language theory. The finite state automaton is quite unstructured. The regular expression however is nested. The operations concatenation, union, and star are similar to programming control constructs, sometimes called sequence, choice and iteration. There are methods to obtain a regular expression from a finite automaton.

@HendrikJan Thanks and exactly my previous learning about the finite automatas made the belief that it is likely possible. The strongest "maybe not" argument was that the goto-less control structures are stack-like, exactly this is why Dijkstra preferred them so much, and stack automatas (representing the context-independent languages) are already much lesser funny (for example, they are not even closed for intersection).

Yes, it's possible, but the construction is probably a lot less satisfying than you imagine it being ;)
Each program can be expressed using only goto <line> and if <condition> then goto <line> end if for branching (imagine some old-school basic dialect).
So if you have a program
stmt-1
stmt-2
.
.
.
stmt-n

in this form, then it can be translated into the equivalent
pc := 1
while (pc <= n) do
    if pc == 1      then stmt-1'; pc := pc + 1 end if
    else if pc == 2 then stmt-2'; pc := pc + 1 end if
    .
    .
    .
    else if pc == n then stmt-n'; pc := pc + 1 end if
end while

where pc is a "fresh" variable name, and stmt-i' is just stmt-i but with all occurences of goto <line> replaced by pc := <line> - 1.

Aieehhh.... that is imho more like an interpreter :-)
